# How to extract multiple URLs seperted by | in a single cell in google sheet using python

Tags: python, extract

I have multiple urls in a single cell for eg:

```
https://www.jotform.com/uploads/prashant1508/201524278582053/4779305729913336783/Ashish Kumar_2020-Sep-21_2020-Oct-06.xlsx.xlsx | https://www.jotform.com/uploads/prashant1508/201524278582053/4779305729913336783/Brijesh Gupta_2020-Sep-17_2020-Oct-02.xlsx.xlsx | https://www.jotform.com/uploads/prashant1508/201524278582053/4779305729913336783/Dhanveer_2020-Sep-16_2020-Sep-30.xlsx.xlsx |
```

which are separated by `|` in google sheet. I want to separate each URL and download them using python. Can some one help

Comment: use `split('|')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `split()`.
With your addresses:

```
urls = https://www.jotform.com/uploads/prashant1508/201524278582053/4779305729913336783/Ashish Kumar_2020-Sep-21_2020-Oct-06.xlsx.xlsx | https://www.jotform.com/uploads/prashant1508/201524278582053/4779305729913336783/Brijesh Gupta_2020-Sep-17_2020-Oct-02.xlsx.xlsx | https://www.jotform.com/uploads/prashant1508/201524278582053/4779305729913336783/Dhanveer_2020-Sep-16_2020-Sep-30.xlsx.xlsx | 
urlList = urls.split(" | ")
```